# Configure a reverse proxy on Heroku Bamboo stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, reverse-proxy

I have a Heroku-hosted site that needs to make AJAX requests to a non-Heroku subdomain.  In the non-Heroku past I've done this with a reverse proxy (to sub.my.domain ) in Apache in order to overcome the browser security model.

I'd like to avoid code changes (e.g. switch to JSONP) at this point. How do I set up a reverse proxy on Heroku, or do you think another option is best like creating a reverse proxy elsewhere and proxying both main and sub domains?

Answer (score 0):

the Heroku support team is top-notch, you should consider asking them for help.

```
support@heroku.com
```